# Algebra for programming

Tags: linear-algebra

I am right now studying *Linear Algebra*. A lot of people say it is important for programming but I can't understand why, since computers perform calculatations so much better than us.

**My question is:** If I become an algebra expert, will it give me an advantage as a professional?

Comment: Knowledge is very important. You never know what will be required after 5, 10 or 20 years... if you really decide to be programmer. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Linear Algebra is widely used in machine learning, signal processing, and computer graphics. If you are to be a professional programmer in one of these fields, knowing linear algebra will likely make a positive difference in your career.

Comment: I just cant understand how I am going to use  concepts such as vetorial space. I think its very beautiful but i cant imagine how I can use it.

Comment: One easily understood use for vector spaces is coordinate transformations and translations. When you move an object through 3d space, you are translating the vectors. When you rotate the object, you are performing a vector coordinate transformation. If you are studying LinAlg as a pure math course, you won't directly learn the computer applications such as 3D graphics, but the latter depends on it. But there are certainly many successful programmers who know little or no LinAlg.